# Different authentication keys in different devise models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for two models. I want to make authentication key of one is phone and other is email. How to manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first model add:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, authentication_keys: [:email]
```

And in your second model add:

```
 devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, authentication_keys: [:phone]
```

Hope this will work for you, for more information follow [Link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)